# How to get access to some of the information of current process in linux kernel

Tags: c, process, linux-kernel

I am very new in kernel coding . So please excuse me I am asking a very dump question

I am trying to get a hold to all of the information of currently running process in the kernel linux. 
Here is what I have tried:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include "process_ancestors.h"

asmlinkage long sys_prs_anc(int arg){
    //int counter = 0;
    long pid;
    char *process_name;
    long process_state;
    long process_owner_uid;
    long voluntary_context_switches;
    long involuntary_context_switches;
    long num_children;
    long num_siblings;
    struct list_head *pos;

    num_children = 0;
    num_siblings = 0;
    struct list_head children_list;
    struct list_head siblings_list;
    pid = current->pid;
    process_name = current->comm;
    process_state=current->state;
    process_owner_uid = (current->cred)->uid;
    children_list = current->children;
    siblings_list = current->sibling;
    voluntary_context_switches = current->nivcsw;
    involuntary_context_switches = current->nvcsw;

    list_for_each(pos, &children_list){
        num_children ++;
    }
    list_for_each(pos, &siblings_list){
        num_siblings ++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

and I get the following error when I build it ?

```
  CHK     include/config/kernel.release
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CC      cs300/process_ancestors.o
cs300/process_ancestors.c: In function ‘sys_process_ancestors’:
cs300/process_ancestors.c:21:2: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
  struct list_head children_list;
  ^
cs300/process_ancestors.c:26:6: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘long int’ from type ‘kuid_t’
  uid = (current->cred)->uid;
      ^
make[1]: *** [cs300/process_ancestors.o] Error 1
make: *** [cs300] Error 2
```

Can any one give me some hints what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

uid is of type `kuid_t`

```
typedef struct {
    uid_t val;
} kuid_t;
```

you should use `process_owner_uid = (current->cred)->uid.val;`

Comment: ...and also he should use `uid_t` type for his `process_owner_uid` variable. Because `uid_t` is `unsigned int`, and he uses `long` type, which is signed (and may even have different size that `int`).